# Recylerview not automatically loading data from firebase Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried everything but my data from firebase is not getting loaded automatically when I open the app and I have to click a edittext to load the data.

I have tried

```
  adapter.Update(data);
  recycler.invalidate();
  notifyDataSetChanged();
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please can someone help me out.

EDITED:

I am saving to firebase like this:

```
    public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
    //WRITE IF NOT NULL
    public Boolean save(Spacecraft spacecraft)
    {
        if(spacecraft==null)
        {
            saved=false;
        }else
        {
            try
            {
                db.child("Spacecraft").push().setValue(spacecraft);
                saved=true;
            }catch (DatabaseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved=false;
            }
        }
        return saved;
    }
    //IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST
    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        spacecrafts.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Spacecraft spacecraft=ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class);
            spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);
        }
    }
    //READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST
    public ArrayList<Spacecraft> retrieve() {
        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){

                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
        });
        return spacecrafts;
    }
}
```

My viewholder class

```
public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        propTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.propellantTxt);
        descTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descTxt);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
    {
        this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.getLayoutPosition());
    }
```

My adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
        this.c = c;
        this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  Spacecraft s=spacecrafts.get(position);
        holder.nameTxt.setText(s.getName());
        holder.propTxt.setText(s.getPropellant());
        holder.descTxt.setText(s.getDescription());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos) {
                //OPEN DETAI ACTIVITY
                openDetailActivity(s.getName(),s.getDescription(),s.getPropellant());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return spacecrafts.size();
    }
    //OPEN DETAIL ACTIVITY
    private void openDetailActivity(String...details)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(c,DetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("NAME_KEY",details[0]);
        i.putExtra("DESC_KEY",details[1]);
        i.putExtra("PROP_KEY",details[2]);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }
```

in my mainactivity in onCreate I am calling the data like this

```
recycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
spacecraft = new ArrayList<>();
firebasehelper = new FirebaseHelper(database);
adapter = new JAdapter(getActivity(), firebasehelper.retrieve());
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Post the code of observer by which you are getting data

Comment: Hi, I have pasted a link to the tutorial I watched to read firebase data. Please let me know if you would like me to paste the code here. I have written exactly the same code.

Comment: Post your code and your video. Not from where you learnt

Comment: Please see update

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `retrieve` method: it's adding a `ChildEventListener` that executes *asynchronously* (meaning it doesn't block until the children data are fetched) and then it immediately returns the `spacecrafts` list which is still not yet filled by the asynchronous listener code.

You should refresh the `RecyclerView` adapter in the actual code that fetches data, i.e. in the `fetchData` method, e.g.:

```
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    spacecrafts.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        Spacecraft spacecraft=ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class);
        spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);
    }
    adapter.spacecrafts = spacecrafts; // update the list in the adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // refresh
}
```

In this case, the `retrieve` method can have a `void` return type as it is pointless to return the list from it.

Comment: its not reconsigning adapter in fetchData

Comment: @JoshJoe I didn't intend for my snippet to be copied exactly as it is. The idea is that you should find way to call the adapter from your `FirebaseHelper`. You can either pass the adapter in a constructor, or pass a callback interface to the `retrieve` method, and this callback gets called when fetching all children is done.

Comment: I been playing around with, but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: The app crashes not matter how I put the adpater there

Answer (score 0):

Use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for load the data from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

modify the helper constructer to be like this:

```
 public FirebaseHelper(Context c, DatabaseReference db, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.db = db;
    this.lv = lv;
}
```

then add this to the fetchData method after the for loop:

```
if (spacecrafts.size() > 0)
    {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(c, spacecrafts);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

then in the main activity modify it like this:

```
    helper = new FirebaseHelper(this, db, lv);
    //ADAPTER
    //adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, helper.retrieve());
    //lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    helper.retrieve();
```

this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are setting up adapter in onCreate() method or not, if you are calling it in onStart() then it will not load data automatically. Set Adapter in onCreate() method.